# Wordpress - get only title and image from get_the_content

Tags: regex, image, wordpress

I'm doing a favor for a friend looking to have a page with all the posts displayed with only the title and the first embedded image from the post. Not a featured image (or post-thumbnail), but one that is part of the post content.

Since it's a favor I haven't requested FTP access and am simply using the "display posts" plugin which uses get_the_content to display the posts.

Is there a way (regex?) to extract the image? I can get the title from other methods obviously, but what if the image is embedded? Is it still attached and available to use from get_post_thumbnail, etc?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php preg_match("#<img(.+?)src=(.+?)\/>#", $post->post_content, $matches);
    /** $matches is an array, $matches[0] holds the img code */
echo $matches[0]; ?>
<?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extract a title using `get_the_content`. What you could do is (as you said) use regular expressions to get the first image element of the content (which has been inserted through the WP post editor). Also getting a short excerpt from the beginning of the content is possible.

If you need to get the post title, you need to use a function for it (e.g. `get_the_title`) or fetch the post object and use its `post_title` value.

`get_post_thumbnail` gets the image attachment that is set as the posts featured image. All the images that reside in the content area must either be extracted with a query or by regex. With the query you would use two extra variables: `post_parent` to get the child "posts" of a certain post and `post_type` to query only for attachment posts (images, etc.).

If you're restricted to using the plugin (and `get_the_content`), you may need to use some tricks to get the title. You can certainly use regex to extract the first available `img` element if needed.

EDIT: I may have misunderstood a bit, you do have access to `get_the_title` yes, no worries on that part then.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below function quite a few times to get the first image in the content and works very well:

```
  function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

then you just need to echo it out like this:

```
<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used @wonderdojo's answer as a starting point, but was led to the below article, in which I finally found a solution that retains all image attributes such as class and title.

```
<?php
           $beforeEachImage = "<div>";
           $afterEachImage = "</div>";
           preg_match_all("/(<img [^>]*>)/",get_the_content(),$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
           for( $i=0; isset($matches[1]) && $i < count($matches[1]); $i++ ) {
                 echo $beforeEachImage . $matches[1][$i] . $afterEachImage;
           }
        ?
```

http://chrisschuld.com/2009/11/removing-everything-but-images-in-a-wordpress-post/

Answer (score 0):

hi by this code you can make gallery from your code very very easily. enjoy!

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?>// five is number of post // you want by this you can make gallery

<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
    <?php preg_match("#<img(.+?)src=(.+?)\/>#", $post->post_content, $images);
echo $images[0]; ?>
<?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile;  ?>
<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```