How to get Custom Post Type attachment URL in WordPress
I have a Custom Post Type called Form and I am attaching only a PDF file in the post using the post editor like this

I have loop like
    <?php 
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'form',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 200, 
    'orderby' => 'publish-date', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'forms',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'personal-services',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query ->the_post(); 
    
    ?>
    <div class="card mb-3 news-card">
        <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card-body pb-0 pt-3">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h5>
                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6  mb-2 pt-3">
                            <span class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Published at: <?php echo get_the_date('l F j, Y' ); ?></small></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12 mb-2">
                            <span role="button" class="card-text new-btn d-block rounded">Download - <?php echo pdf_attachment_file("1",""); ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    
    
    ?>

the <?php echo get_the_content(); ?> is exporting the PDF file on the page but I need to get the URL of the attachment. How can I achieve this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938124/wordpress-get-only-title-and-image-from-get-the-content
